# Filling and iterating over a hash of arrays in Perl

Tags: perl, data-structures, reference

What I want to do is organise a bunch of config parameters depending on device IP.

For each IP there's a list of indexes (`$row`) which I must have to generate the config for that particular IP.

(these indexes are my 'data' in this context. Don't look at them as indexes, they are the thing I must put there and then get them during config generation).

The Data I need to 'group' may look something like this...

```
$routerIP    $row (an index to a global hash containing various details)
10.10.10.10  2
10.10.10.12  1
10.10.10.10  0
10.10.10.12  3
```

So I want to get (and I do, looking at printouts!)

```
$ipGroup{$10.10.10.10}[1] = 2
$ipGroup{$10.10.10.10}[2] = 0

$ipGroup{$10.10.10.12}[1] = 1
$ipGroup{$10.10.10.12}[2] = 3
```

I fill my `%ipGroup` in a loop that will go through the Data:

```
my $routerIP = #code to get the ip
my $ind = $ipGroup{$routerIP}[0]+1;
$ipGroup{$routerIP}[0] = $ind;     
$ipGroup{$routerIP}[$ind] = $row;
```

Quick and dirty store a 'current index' `$ind` in the 0th element in the array for each IP
for that latest `$ind` put the current `$row`. This way progressing in the array for that `$routerIP` key.

How I read the group in a different subroutine (%isGroup is global):

```
foreach $routerIP (keys %ipGroup) {

    my @rows = @{$ipGroup{$routerIP}};

    my $index = 0;

    while ($rows[$index]) {
        $index++;
        my $row = $rows[$index];

    # do stuff here
    }
}
```

The problem is:

Although it iterates for each routerIP It doesn't go through all the `@rows` For The Last Router that was in the hash

So with the data above id get a proper config for 10.10.10.10 with all the stuff for `$row=2` and `$row=0`
but for 10.10.10.12 id get only config for `$row=3`?!

How come it iterates for all rows for one key but not another, printing the arrays for each hash key I've seen they are different, I don't simply have 1 array referenced in both $hash values. 
With all the looping options and referencing and dereferencing data structure initialization I am thoroughly confused.

the code upon filling (when filling the `$row` is named `$hashId`)
`print "updated router: $routerIP index: $ind hashId: $hashId <br />";`

```
updated router: 10.10.10.10 index: 1 hashId: 0 
updated router: 10.10.10.10 index: 2 hashId: 1 
updated router: 10.10.10.12 index: 1 hashId: 2 
updated router: 10.10.10.12 index: 2 hashId: 3 
updated router: 10.10.10.10 index: 3 hashId: 4
```

Data Dump after filling is complete:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '10.10.10.12' => [
                               2,
                               '2',
                               '3'
                             ],
          '10.10.10.10' => [
                               3,
                               '0',
                               '1',
                               '4'
                             ]
        };
```

in the inner while loop from the code:
`print "in loop: $routerIP index: $index hashId: <br />";`

```
in loop: 10.10.10.12 index: 1 hashId: 2 
in loop: 10.10.10.12 index: 2 hashId: 3 
in loop: 10.10.10.12 index: 3 hashId: 
in loop: 10.10.10.10 index: 1 hashId: 0
```

I see discrepancies but I'm at a loss, been hours on this.

Comment: I would say that the problem is almost certainly in the code that builds the hash. This looks like a classic case of the last data item read not being flushed after a `while` loop.

Please show more of the code that imports the data

Comment: Please also provide a dump of the hash:  `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%ipGroup;`

Comment: Yes, please bear with me while I add as much as possible

Comment: There are examples in [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), the Perl Data Structures Cookbook.

Comment: Indeed but I've been fast-tracked to this task and really had no time, still getting to grips with perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this. It uses all references and is pretty clean.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

# Setup a reference to a HASH
my $ipGroup = {};


# Populate your structure with __DATA__
foreach my $item (<DATA>) {

        $item =~ m/([0-9\.]+)\s(.*)/;

        # Push the "row" onto an array dynamically      
        push @{$ipGroup->{$1}}, $2;

}

foreach my $routerIP ( keys %{$ipGroup} ) {

        foreach my $row ( @{$ipGroup->{$routerIP}} ) {

                print "Doing stuff to $routerIP with index [ $row ] \n";

        }


}
```

I just put the data you provided directly in the file, you may need to change this.

```
__DATA__
10.10.10.10  2
10.10.10.12  1
10.10.10.10  0
10.10.10.12  3
```

Comment: Thats essentially what I want to do yes Im giving it a go now, again with the Perl syntax wizardry, love and hate at the same time ahah.

Comment: You should test the result regex any time you do a match before doing anything else.  You could have a line in the source file that doesn't match the regex and then you'll be pushing the pervious line's $2 into @{$ipGroup->{$1}} again.